# JS Date object - return human readable string without time

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working with a string of data in this format: "mm-dd-yy". I convert this to a Date object in this way:

```
var dateData, dateObject, dateReadable, dateSplit, year, month, day;

dateData = "07-21-14"; //For example

dateSplit = dateData.split('-');

month = dateSplit[0] - 1;
day = dateSplit[1];
year = 20 + dateSplit[2];

dateObject = new Date(year, month, day);

dateReadable = dateObject.toUTCString(); //Returns Mon, 21 Jul 2014 04:00:00 GMT
```

I would like to return the date (Mon, 21 Jul 2014) without the time (04:00:00 GMT). Is there a different method that will do so? Or a way of calling `.toUTCString()` to return the date without the time?

Comment: Like `new Date().toString().split(' ').splice(0, 4).join(' ')`?

Comment: Looking for something that doesn't involve manually removing the time.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I believe you want `.toDateString()` or `.toLocaleDateString()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

In fact, you should also look at Date.parse():

```
var dateData, dateObject, dateReadable;

dateData = "07-21-14"; //For example

dateObject = new Date(Date.parse(dateData));

dateReadable = dateObject.toDateString();
```

Comment: Edited to also add in Date.parse(), which avoids splitting the original string.

Comment: toLocaleString() gives the time component as well as date: 05/07/2021, 7:44:00 pm